# Want to check the type of a class by comparing it with its static member

Tags: c#, .net

I have a parent class, Command, that has a const name and a virtual method called execute; both are overwritten by children.  I have a method that takes a list of commands and returns a potentially modified list of commands.

To determine whether or not the input command list should be changed, I need to know the type of each command in the list before making changes to this list.  The problem though is that I have to use the new keyword in order to create a static member for the derived class with the same name as the parent but I want to be able to statically reference the name of a command.

Example of what I'm trying to do:

```
public List<Command> ReplacementEffect(List<Command> exChain)
{
    for(int index = 0; index < exChain.Count; index++)
    {
         if(exChain[index].Name == StaticReference.Name)
         {
             //Modify exChain here
         }
    }
    return exChain;
}
```

The problem with using exChain[index].GetType() is that I have to instantiate another object of that type just to check which is wasteful, time consuming and not intuitive.  Also, I would have to remove the const modifier from Name.

Edit:

```
class Command
{
    public const string Name = "Null";

    public virtual void Execute()
    {
        //Basic implementation
    }
}

class StaticReference : Command
{
    public new const string Name = "StaticRef";

    public override void Execute()
    {
        //New implementation
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand why this can't be handled by getting the type of the derived class like with 'if(exChain[index].Name is StaticReference)'?

Comment: Side note: Showing minimal portion of `Command` class could make this question better... Also "use the `new` keyword in order to..." usually produces code with strange behavior, so it may be good idea to expand on why you find `item.GetType() == typeof(SomeType)` or `item is SomeType` non-intuitive... Note that there are better ways to do handling groups of types of objects.

Comment: You don't need to embed the name of the type *in* the type. You can do `obj is TheType` for easy checking. Setting that aside, type-checking with derived classes is typically an anti-pattern, no matter how you go about doing it.

Comment: Static members cannot be accessed by an instance of a class, only static references to them may be made.  However, I want to be able to statically reference the name of the class in other methods.

Comment: Ah I had not seen the "is" keyword, this is the functionality I was looking for.  The reason I need to do type checking on derived classes is because modifying the execution chain is dependent on the order the commands are given in.  IE: If I have a command that says "give an apple" but there is an effect that says "before giving an apple, you must take an apple", the command list must change from { GiveApple } to { TakeApple, GiveApple } whereas if the list said { GiveBanana } it would have to leave the list unmodified.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really can't use type comparison `exChain[index].GetType() == typeof(StaticReference)` because of derived classes that will both be of type `StaticReference` but you want to differentiate via `Name` (not shown in your example - but if that's not the case, use type comparison instead), you can use a static property for the name but access it via virtual accessor:

```
class Command
{
    public const string Name = "Null";

    public virtual string CommandName
    {
        get
        {
            return Name;
        }
    }
}

class StaticReference : Command
{
    public new const string Name = "StaticRef";

    public virtual string CommandName
    {
        get
        {
            return Name;
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
     if(exChain[index].CommandName == StaticReference.Name)
     {
         //Modify exChain here
     }
```

Comment: Your solution is correct but your comment about .GetType()==typeof(StaticReference) not working is incorrect since GetType() yields the actual type, not a baseclass type.

Comment: You are correct.  The `is` operator is what I was thinking of.